# Storing version number in a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, version

How should I store the version number of my code inside a ruby gem?

I've seen two techniques in the wild:

1. `<gem root>/VERSION` which only contains your [semver](http://semver.org).
2. `<gem root>/lib/your_gem/version.rb` which contains the following code:

```
module IfYourCodeIsInAModule
  class YourGem
    VERSION="0.0.1"
  end
end
```

I like 1. because it's really obvious. I like 2. because it's part of my code, I can write to logs with my version number easily.

I don't like 1. because if I want to access the version number from within my code I have to do a file read (not the worst thing ever), I don't like 2. because if my core class extends from another class then I have to have that decendency in the `version.rb` too (or else get a `superclass mismatch`) - eg.

```
module IfYourCodeIsInAModule
  class YourGem < OtherWork
    VERSION = "0.0.1"
  end
end
```

When you require this file from your actual code for runtime it's all good. When you include it in your gemspec you suddenly need to  `require 'other_work'` to get your Version number!

I'm happy to go and roll my own solution, but this can't be a new problem, what's the community doing, and what's the general wisdom on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert on gem VERSION ethnology, but perhaps this non-expertise makes me all the more average and better suited to answer the questions on "general wisdom".

So, general wisdom is, [use Bundler](http://gembundler.com). And once you create your gem by `bundle gem my_gem_name`, you will see that the bundler automatically creates `lib/my_gem_name/version.rb` file and requires it from your `lib/my_gem_name.rb`. So I would suggest that if you decide not to use bundler and roll your own gem on your own, you still should keep a separate `version.rb` file containing only

```
module MyGemName
  VERSION = "0.0.1"
end
```

That is, straight under the main module. You then load the `version.rb` from `lib/my_gem_name.rb`. Of course, if your code is organized in a more alien way, then you need to improvize more.

Comment: So how would you deal with a gem which supplies a single class (which inherits from a class within a dependency)? I think you're suggesting I wrap it in a module just for versioning's sake: `module Rack; module MyCoolThing; VERSION = "0.0.1"; end; end` - and then in my actual code:  `module Rack; module MyCoolThing; class MyCoolThing; def awesomes; end; end; end; end` - this seems awkward!

Comment: @JP: That's up to you. But in *.gemspec file created by Bundler, you can define different version location than MyCoolThing::VERSION. It can be `module Rack; class MyCoolThing; VERSION = '0.0.1'; def awesomes end end end`. And in *gemspec, you say that version is stored under Rack::MyCoolThing::VERSION and there you go.

Comment: It's this situation where the difficulty arises - if `MyCoolThing` inherits from `GiantLibrary` then I need to declare that inheritance in the version file too (`require 'giant_library'; module Rack; class MyCoolThing < GiantLibrary; VERSION = '0.0.1'; end; end`) but then I have to load `giant_library` in order to declare my version number! This seems wrong…

Comment: It is like this: If your `CoolThing` has individuality as a library (gem), then it needs its own namespace. This can be `::CoolThing`, or `::My::CoolThing` (Where `My` is your name/brand), and there the version is declared. Then, when the time comes to `require 'giant_library'`, your `CoolThing` is included in `Rack` like this: `module Rack; include ::My::CoolThing end`. However, if your cool thing does not have individuality and is just a modification to rack, then you should submit it to the rack crew for inclusion, accepting their versioning policy. The third option is to fork rack.